# Discrete log accumulator without pairings?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, accumulators

Here $g$ is some fixed generator of a discrete log group. I don't want the group to be bilinear for efficiency and BDH-skepticism reasons.

Is anyone aware of a discrete log accumulator? What I mean specifically is some function $f(x, A)\mapsto A'$ (that is, $A$ is the accumulator value; $f$ adds $x$ to the accumulator, changing its value to $A'$) such that given $(g^x, A')$ anyone can check whether $x$ was placed in the accumulator.

So I'm roughly asking for an accumulator with the property that an accumulated element $x$ has $g^x$ as a witness.

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  Use the strong RSA assumption.  The accumulator of $x_1,\dots,x_k$ is $A = g^{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k} \bmod n$, where $n$ is a RSA modulus and $g$ is a fixed base.  To prove that the accumulator $A$ contains $x$, exhibit a value $h$ such that $h^x=A \pmod n$.  This is secure under the strong RSA assumption, and has a discrete log "feel" to it.

Comment: According to the [original paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24) by Benaloh and de Mare, the RSA modulus in this case should be chosen s.t. the order of $g$ has no small prime factors (and $g$ doesn't have to generate the complete multiplicative group). One stated example is both $p$ and $q$ being safe primes and $g$ having order $(p-1)/2 \cdot (q-1)/2$ (which is a product of two large primes)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of the vector commitment (VC) schemes by Catalano and Fiore comes closest to what you need [[1]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/495.pdf). Specifically, the one based on Computational Diffie Hellman (CDH) (see Section 3.1 in their paper).

You might also be able to verify membership of $x$ using $g^x$ rather than $x$ itself if you can use a discrete log equality proof between the VC's ${h_i}^x$ used during verification in $\mathsf{VC.Ver}$ and your $g^x$.

**Later edit:** I did not include the accumulator based on Strong RSA since you *only* mentioned discrete log as an assumption. If you're okay with Strong RSA, there is a way to check that a committed element is in the accumulator (see ["Dynamic accumulators and application to efficient revocation of anonymous credentials"](https://cs.brown.edu/people/alysyans/papers/camlys02.pdf), by Camenisch & Lysyanskaya).